# Express creating new session on every request when cookie is used

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

When I use cookie in express-session, on every request a new session is created with new session id.

I am using redis store to store sessions.

This my middleware code.

```
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  rolling: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: config.SESSION_SECRET,
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: redis_host,
    port: redis_port,
    pass: redis_pass
  }),
  cookie : {
    domain : '.soulskill.com',
    secure : secureBoolean,
    maxAge : 2592000000, // 1-Month
  }
}));
```

PS : I am not using cookie parser.

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is set and send back to the server on a new request?

Comment: The cookie was not getting parsed on the server side. I figured out that the version of express-session i was using was old and it was not parsing cookies. Thankyou so much for helping to think through a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

express-session version was 1.13 which was not able to parse the cookies ,
upgraded the express-session to the latest version 1.15.6.

now the cookies are getting parsed on the server end.

Answer (score 0):

Set `rolling: false` in the session options